# Trying to get a value from a temp table to an Access subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have tried this via macro and by VBA code (not an expert at all).  I just want to get the value of TEMP_AMT from my one record table tmpTbl_TEMP_AMT and store that value in my subform in the TotalAmount control.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `DLookup` function?

Comment: How was this value generated and saved to temp table? Saving calculated data is usually bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is first have to fetch that value :

```
select fieldName from tableName;
```

and assign this returned value to text box of form.

```
formName!textBoxName = fieldName.
```